# How to see celery tasks in redis queue when there is no worker?

Tags: django-celery

I have a container creating celery tasks, and a container running a worker.
I have removed the worker container, so I expected that tasks would accumulate in the redis list of tasks.
But I can't see any tasks in redis.

This is with django. I need to isolate the worker and queue, hence the settings
A typical queue name is 'test-dear', that is, SHORT_HOSTNAME='test-dear'

```
CELERY_DATABASE_NUMBER = 0
CELERY_BROKER_URL = f"redis://{REDIS_HOST}:6379/{CELERY_DATABASE_NUMBER}"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = f"redis://{REDIS_HOST}:6379/{CELERY_DATABASE_NUMBER}"
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'global_keyprefix': SHORT_HOSTNAME }
CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE = SHORT_HOSTNAME
CELERY_TASK_ACKS_LATE = True
```

After starting everything, and stopping the worker, I add tasks.
For example, on the producer container after python manage.py shell

```
>>> from cached_dear import tasks
>>> t1 = tasks.purge_deleted_masterdata_fast.delay()
<AsyncResult: 9c9a564a-d270-444c-bc71-ff710a42049e>
```

`t1.get()` does not return.

then in redis:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> llen test-dear
(integer) 0
```

I was not expecting 0 entries.

What I am doing wrong or not understanding?

Answer (score 0):

I did this from the redis container

```
redis-cli monitor | grep test-dear
```

and sent a task.

The list is `test-deartest-dear` and

```
llen test-deartest-dear
```

works to show the number of tasks which have not yet been sent to a worker.

The queue name is f"{global_keyprefix}{queue_name}

Comment: I did not understand what you did. Can you please take a look at my question and help me?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75630058/get-list-of-all-keys-in-redis-created-by-celery-for-tasks-in-flask-app

Comment: I use the redis command llen to get the length of the task queue, since I know the name of the task queue.