# Get list of all keys in redis created by celery for tasks in Flask app

Tags: python, redis, celery

I have two containers which are running `Python Flask` apps let's say 1 and 2. Number 1 communicates with Redis and creates below messages in `redis-cli monitor`:

```
1677744862.693857 [0 192.168.80.13:44076] "SUBSCRIBE" "celery-task-meta-11902e64-94cc-4e02-89ce-3cea365294bb"
1677744862.694585 [0 192.168.80.13:44044] "PING"
1677744862.694949 [0 192.168.80.13:44044] "LPUSH" "celery" "{"body": "siDxNiIICwDfDwzDwiINcyWt5ZZd0WiCiwIEXg30Is2sGhtIons", "content-encoding": "utf-8", "content-type": "application/json", "headers": {"lang": "py", "task": "task.send_text", "id": "11902e64-94cc-4e02-89ce-3cea365294bb", "shadow": null, "eta": null, "expires": null, "group": null, "group_index": null, "retries": 0, "timelimit": [null, null], "root_id": "11902e64-94cc-4e02-89ce-3cea365294bb", "parent_id": null, "argsrepr": "('123456', '000_000_000_000', '000000', 'DefaultId', '', '1')", "kwargsrepr": "{}", "origin": "gen74@f0eb8cc30754", "ignore_result": false}, "properties": {"correlation_id": "11902e64-94cc-4e02-89ce-3cea365294bb", "reply_to": "7fdc8466-0de3-3be1-8a0a-a48713e2769a", "delivery_mode": 2, "delivery_info": {"exchange": "", "routing_key": "celery"}, "priority": 0, "body_encoding": "base64", "delivery_tag": "b5cc708a-8f28-4fb1-8714-1de4433c8621"}}"
1677744862.696078 [0 192.168.80.13:44076] "UNSUBSCRIBE" "celery-task-meta-11902e64-94cc-4e02-89ce-3cea365294bb
```

and then container 2 communicates below messages:

```
1677744993.925599 [0 192.168.80.12:43034] "GET" "celery-task-meta-11902e64-94cc-4e02-89ce-3cea365294bb"
1677744993.927298 [0 192.168.80.12:43034] "MULTI"
1677744993.927340 [0 192.168.80.12:43034] "SETEX" "celery-task-meta-11902e64-94cc-4e02-89ce-3cea365294bb" "86400" "{"status": "SUCCESS", "result": ["True", "", "123456"], "traceback": null, "children": [], "date_done": "2023-03-02T08:16:33.922182", "task_id": "11902e64-94cc-4e02-89ce-3cea365294bb"}"
1677744993.927480 [0 192.168.80.12:43034] "PUBLISH" "celery-task-meta-11902e64-94cc-4e02-89ce-3cea365294bb" "{"status": "SUCCESS", "result": ["True", "", "123456"], "traceback": null, "children": [], "date_done": "2023-03-02T08:16:33.922182", "task_id": "11902e64-94cc-4e02-89ce-3cea365294bb"}"
1677744993.927602 [0 192.168.80.12:43034] "EXEC"
1677744994.868230 [0 192.168.80.12:42992] "BRPOP" "celery" "celery\x06\x163" "celery\x06\x166" "celery\x06\x169" "1"
```

Now let's say 2nd container is down and above messages(starting from "GET") did not happen. How can I get list of all tasks `e.g. celery-task-meta-11902e64-94cc-4e02-89ce-3cea365294bb` that were now finished?
Even when I try `redis-cli info` in `# Keyspace part` the number of keys do not increase for every task that is created by 1st container.
Can you please help? I already tried `Python` code below but these kind of tasks still do not appear.

```py
import redis
import json

redis_client = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
task_ids = redis_client.keys('celery-task-meta-*')

unfinished_tasks = []
number_of_finished = []
for task_id in task_ids:
    task_result = redis_client.get(task_id)
    string = task_result.decode('utf-8')
    dictionary = json.loads(string)
    if "status" not in dictionary:
        unfinished_tasks.append(task_id)

print('Unfinished tasks:', unfinished_tasks)
print(len(unfinished_tasks))
```

Comment: Is "localhost" machine to which all docker containers running Celery workers connect to?

Comment: yes they are all in the same machine and networl

Comment: So all your Celery worker containers connect to "localhost" as broker (Redis)?

Comment: Their `Redis` URL in `Python` code is:
`REDIS_URL = "redis://test-redis:6379"`

Comment: And the script you pasted above that connects to "localhost" actually connects to `test-redis`, right?

Comment: yep I even replaced it with test-redis and the same result came

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252299/discussion-between-john-and-dejanlekic).

Comment: to find the number of items (as per my question that you commented on) you can use the redis command llen to get the length of items in the task queue. But you need to know the name of the task queue.. Probably the Flask documentation helps, or whatever library you are using that gives you Celery queues.

Comment: How to get the name? is it tasker in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using below `bash` script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    count=$(docker exec redis redis-cli llen celery)
    if [ $count -gt 100 ]; then
        echo "Length of Redis list exceeded 100!"
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

Thanks Tim Richardson for helping me out.
`docker exec redis redis-cli llen celery` only tells you the number but you can view the list of tasks using `docker exec redis redis-cli lrange celery 0 -1`
And finally if you are using `Celery`, the name of the task queue is `celery` by default.